# How to get the Facebook insights data for ad Creative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

I'am trying to get the reports data for the Facebook campaign, campaign has 3 adset, 3 ad and each ad has 3 adCreatives. Please can anyone help me in getting the adCreative specific insights data. I tried with the graph API explore i did't get the data for adCreatives.

call made with params are : https://graph.facebook.com/2.9/campaingId-XXXX/insights?fields=impressions,clicks,ctr,ad_name,adset_name,cpc,cpm,cpp,campaign_name,ad_id,adset_id,account_id,account_name&level=ad&metrics=ctr&limit=10

Ex : response from Graph API explorer

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "impressions": "30",
      "clicks": "1",
      "ctr": "3.333333",
      "ad_name": "I Ad",
      "adset_name": "I Ad Set",
      "cpc": "0.03",
      "cpm": "1",
      "cpp": "4.285714",
      "campaign_name": "Campaign.act_xxxxxxx",
      "ad_id": "xxxxx",
      "adset_id": "xxxxx",
      "account_id": "xxxxx",
      "account_name": "Test Account From test",
      "date_start": "2017-04-17",
      "date_stop": "2017-05-16"
    },
    {
      "impressions": "28",
      "clicks": "0",
      "ctr": "0",
      "ad_name": "H Ad",
      "adset_name": "H Ad Set",
      "cpc": "0",
      "cpm": "1.071429",
      "cpp": "3.75",
      "campaign_name": "Campaign.act_xxxxxxx",
      "ad_id": "xxxxxx",
      "adset_id": "xxxxx",
      "account_id": "xxxxxx",
      "account_name": "Test Account From test",
      "date_start": "2017-04-17",
      "date_stop": "2017-05-16"
    },
    {
      "impressions": "29",
      "clicks": "2",
      "ctr": "6.896552",
      "ad_name": "G Ad",
      "adset_name": "G Ad Set",
      "cpc": "0.025",
      "cpm": "1.724138",
      "cpp": "8.333333",
      "campaign_name": "Campaign.act_xxxxxxx",
      "ad_id": "xxxxxx",
      "adset_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "account_id": "xxxxxxxx",
      "account_name": "Test Account From test",
      "date_start": "2017-04-17",
      "date_stop": "2017-05-16"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MgZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it wrong. You have only one ad creative per ad. You see 3 item in your list because you querying on campaign level. So basically you have 1 campaign 3 adsets and 3 ads.

1 ad creative could be use in multiple ads, but 1 ad can use only one creative at a time.

Comment: Artyom, but in my case in a ad creative there are 4 product how can i get the insights for each of the products.

Comment: Did you mean "multi-product ad"? Advert where you can click left/right arrows to see different items? I am not sure it is possible to spit it this way. May be it make sens to create one ad per product. Can you provide more info?

Comment: Artyom, yes that ad will be in the form of carousel with multiple product. i got that i can get data by each product wise by using the breakdown=product_id param in graph API explore, here am not getting how to get the product name.

Comment: Are you sure, this is working with carousel/multi-product ads? I think it is something from dynamic ads and product catalog. Btw, your link above does not contains breakdown parameter

Comment: Artyom Yes, mine ad is using product catalogue.. i was missing the breakdowns param. after passing the breakdowns param i got the expected data.. Thanks Artyom.

Comment: Welcome! Please accept my post as correct answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Each ad can have only one creative, therefore the best way forward is to list all the ads within an account and project creative info. You can try the following graph query:

`/act_{{AD_ACCOUNT_ID}}/ads?fields=adcreatives{body,effective_object_story_id,object_url,thumbnail_url,image_url,object_type},insights.date_preset(lifetime).level(ad).breakdowns(publisher_platform){spend,clicks,impressions,reach,actions,unique_actions,video_p25_watched_actions,video_p50_watched_actions,video_p75_watched_actions,video_p95_watched_actions,video_p100_watched_actions,video_10_sec_watched_actions},id,name,campaign{id,name,account_id,objective},adset{id,name},created_time&limit=250&effective_status=['ACTIVE','ARCHIVED','PAUSED','CAMPAIGN_PAUSED','ADSET_PAUSED']`